# Add list to list issue

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datetime, charts

I have same type of 2 object lists and first item of first list should be added specific times. Also every cycle i should increase the datetime value with `AddSeconds()`. This is my code below:

```
List<Logs> logList = new List<Logs>();
List<Logs> chartList = new List<Logs>();

for (int i = 0; i < specificValue; i++)
{
    chartList.Add(logList[0]);
    logList[0].Date = logList[0].Date.AddSeconds(1);                    
}
```

My purpose is creating chart data with change log so i have to add same value to chartList with specific time with incremental date value. But my problem this code creates a chartList with all the same value of the last loglist item. I found some solutions with using foreach but in that situation i have to use for loop.

Comment: You're never adding items to `logList` but you're accessing the first. So this is not all code.

Comment: @un-lucky I think u didnt read my explanation all, I need the same value with specific time to show the no change on chart. ı just change date value(+1 seconds)

Comment: @un-lucky, OP clearly says *and first item of first list should be added specific times*. Did you miss that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter my loglist already has values so i didnt feel i need to show that

Comment: I tried your code with sample data and it worked without any problem...

Comment: @diiN_ did you check about datetime? cos in the list i just have the last datetime i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `chartList.Add(logList[0])`, you are adding a reference to the object, not creating a new object.

So on the next line, when you add 1 second to the object, you also add that 1 second to the object in `chartList`. In fact, all the objects in `chartList` are references to the exact same object.

You need to create a copy of the object when you add it to `chartList`.

Comment: if you mean this, I have tried also
Logs log = new Logs();
  log = logList[0];
  log.Date = log.Date .AddSeconds(1);
  chartList.Add(log);
Can you explain me that on the code?

Comment: For emphasis, the important part here is "are references to the exact same object".  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c) for more information.

Comment: @CanESER As soon as you do `log = logList[0];`, you are making the variable a reference to logList[0], and the new object you created with `log = new Logs()` will go to the garbage collector. You need to make an actual copy. One way would be to create a copy constructor in the Logs class, then create the new object with `Logs log = new Logs(logList[0])`;

Comment: @Eli u are my hero! I was trying to fix that problem since morning. I realized i know so less about objects. But now everything is well with ur help. Thank you so much

Comment: @CanESER My pleasure :)